# How to add an if statement into this php function

Tags: php, wordpress, numbers, cart, woocommerce

I need to insert an `if` statement in the code below:

```
add_filter('add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment');
function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    ob_start();
?>
    <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" 
       title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>">

        <?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items',
                $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), 
                $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - 
        <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>

    </a>
    <?php
        $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();
        return $fragments;
}
```

This is for woocommerce. It displays cart by content number.
I need an `if` statement similar to this:

```
if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents ) == 0 ) {
echo 'empty cart';
}
else ...
```

So that when the cart is empty it displays a message. I don't know how to write this into that function.

Comment: Emaxx Zeppie: Can you pls clarify one thing??? `$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count` is a number (**not an array**) right???

Comment: cart_contents_count returns an integer

Comment: in that case just `if(($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count) == 0)` is more than enough... `sizeof()` is not needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace this**:

```
<a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" 
   title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>">

    <?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items',
            $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), 
            $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - 
    <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>

</a>
```

---

**With this**:

```
<?php if((sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents)) == 0): 
    echo 'empty cart';
?>
<?php else: ?>
  <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" 
       title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>">

        <?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items',
                $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), 
                $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - 
        <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>

    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It still does display the "else" condition even if I have zero items in my cart

Comment: @EmanueleEmaxxZeppieri I just left a comment... :) `sizeof($var)` == `count($var)` in **PHP** so Even if the value of `$var` (integer) is 0 or anything, `sizeof($var)` 'll be always 1

Comment: I got it ! The correct one is "cart_contents", not "cart_contents_count". Now, It does work :D Thank you so much !

Comment: so its `sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents)` or `intval($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count)`

Comment: sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents) does the trick for me